# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined (React JS)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I'm crating a function recursive, It should go over object type ItemType, so I'm having an error, this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

this's code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

type ItemType = {
  id: Number;
  title: String;
  children: Array<Number>;
};

// Each "ItemType" element in the array have a array of children ID's. These refer
// to a ItemType.
// = This has a infinite depth.
const items: ItemType[] = [
  { id: 1, title: "Item 1", children: [2, 3, 4] },
  { id: 2, title: "Item 2", children: [1, 3, 4] },
  { id: 3, title: "Item 3", children: [1, 2, 4] },
  { id: 4, title: "Item 3", children: [1, 2, 3] }
];

function Item({ title, children }: ItemType): JSX.Element {
  const [open, toggle] = useState(false);

  // Given the children array with IDs, find each Item we refer to
  const childElements = children.map(findChild) as ItemType[];

  return (
    <div>
      <h6>
        {title} children <button onClick={() => toggle(!open)}>Open</button>
      </h6>
      <ul>
        {/* Loop children and run recursive */}
        {open &&
          childElements.map((child: ItemType) => (
            <li>
              <div>Child: {child.title}</div>
              <Item {...child} />
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Start by iterating over all items */}
      {items.map(item => (
        <Item {...item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

// Function to find a Item by child id.
function findChild(childId: Number): ItemType | undefined {
  return items.find(({ id }) => id === childId);
}

export default App;
```

It code try to go over object type ItemType and find each child of each Item, when it found some child It's true and it should be show or when It don't found some child is false, It code create like a tree of item and show in view, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: At which point do you get that error? And which line?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really common error, basically happens because there isn't any nullability check before calling map, it basically means that the object you're trying to use is undefined.

There might also be an error in your logic where you're trying to find by Id, if there isn't any result then JS will return `undefined`, so you need to refactor your code to either check for `undefined | null` or defaulting to something if there isn't any result in the find function.

```js
let array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Kevin",
    children: [55, 66, 23],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Pietro",
    children: [44, 45, 13],
  },
];

const id = array.map((i) => i.id);
console.log(id); // This will return [1, 2]

// Let's pretend for some reason we didn't get the array, it's undefined or null
array = undefined;

// Option #1: You can default to an empty array with the ?? operator.
const id3 = (array ?? []).map((i) => i.id);
console.log(id3);  // This will return [] (render nothing)

// Option #2: You can cascade your nullability with the ? operator.
const id4 = array?.map((i) => i.id);
console.log(id4); // This will return undefined but won't throw.

// This is your current code, it throws because there's no nulability check.
const id2 = array.map((i) => i.id); // Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
console.log(id2);
```

Answer (score 0):

is the `children` containing at least one id that is present in the `items` array. If not, then `children.map()` might return undefined which will be assigned to `childElements`. In that case, `childElements.map` will give the error `map of undefined`. Because childElements is undefined and `trying to access map from undefined is not possible`.